# left join same structured table with partitioning

Tags: sql, hive, left-join, partitioning

I have two same schema tables :-

```
Table A : vendorname,branch,amount,region (partitioned by year,month,day)
Table B : vendorname,branch,amount,region (partitioned by year,month,day)
```

data in table A :

```
john,c1,112,us
 john,c2,113,uk
 john,c3,199,aus
```

data in table B:

```
john,c1,112,us
  john,c2,113,uk
  john,c3,99,aus
  john,c4,144,br
  john,c5,50,cr
```

Output:

```
john,c3,199,99,aus ==> mismatch for 199 and 99
```

Need compare every record from table A to table B ..there can be additional records in b.
I am trying with left join but not able to do.

Query tried:

```
select * from (
(select vendorname,type,amount,region from A 
where vendorname='john' and  year='2018' and month='01' and day='01' ) t1
left join
(select vendorname,type,amount,region
from B
where vendorname='john' and  year='2018' and month='01' and day='01')t2
on (a.name=b.name and a.type=b.type))
```

but getting nulls for matching column also

I cannot query the whole table as it is partioned we need to pick data from specific partition else it will affect performance

Comment: use right join or shift tables other way round

Comment: can you add some sample output aswel please ?

Comment: in output i have written john ,c3,199,99..the mismatch of amount

Comment: do u also want to return additional columns from table 2?

Comment: Ven means please tell us the expected results

Comment: expected result is the vendor and branch that is mismatched

Comment: @HadoopDeveloper your query should work if u replace a and b with t1 and t2 in join syntax

Comment: yeah..replaced but still i am getting nulls for t2 table @Ven

Comment: Joining on correct columns make difference i guess  t1.name = t2.name,t1.branch = t2.branch and t1.region = t2.region and t1.amount <> t2.amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending upon the output needed

1. All cases where vender name and branch matched but amount not matching

```
select t2.*
  from ((select vendorname, branch, amount, region
           from A 
          where vendorname='john'
            and  year='2018' and month='01'
            and day='01' ) as t1
   join (select vendorname,branch,amount,region
                from B
               where vendorname='john'
                 and year='2018'
                 and month='01'
                 and day='01') as t2
  on (t1.vendorname=t2.vendorname
 and t1.branch=t2.branch))
where t1.amount <> t2.amount
```

2. All cases where vender name and branch matched but amount not matching + additional records in table A + Additional Records in Table B

```
select t1.*, t2.* from 
(select vendorname,branch,amount,region from A 
where vendorname='john' and  year='2018' and month='01' and day='01' ) t1
full outer join
(select vendorname,branch,amount,region
from B
where vendorname='john' and  year='2018' and month='01' and day='01')t2
on (t1.vendorname=t2.vendorname and t1.branch=t2.branch))
where t1.amount <> t2.amount or t1.amount is null or t2.amount is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Full join.  It's the equivalent of left join union right join and will give you all data from both tables.

```
select * from table1 a full join table2 b on a.vendorname=b.vendorname and a.branch=b.branch and a.amount=b.amount and a.region=b.region
where...
```

Comment: in where u mean write partition colums

Comment: put your filters in the where clause like vendorname='john' etc

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.* from A inner join B
on a.vendorname=b.vendorname
and a.branch=b.branch
where a.amount<>b.amount
```

Check here-http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8a352/5

Comment: This does not return additional columns from table b

Comment: i also need data from same partitions only

Comment: There are no matching records for branches c4 and c5 in table a, as you have used inner join it wont return those rows. OP is not very clear in his question

Comment: @HadoopDeveloper - you can apply the partition condition at the end of clause,and the answer given purely gives you mismatch data.

Comment: I guess @HadoopDeveloper you mean filters as Partition ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA A full OUTER JOIN TABLEB B ON a.vendorname = B.vendorname AND  a.branch =b.branch 
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT 1
FROM tableA A RIGHT JOIN tableB B ON a.vendorname = B.vendorname 
AND a.branch =b.branch 
AND a.amount<>b.amount 
AND a.region=b.region)
```

Comment: if you are concerned with performance, try to avoid the inner subquery